# How is temporary memory allocation is fast when compared to the explicitly creating String objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, object, memory

It is generally recommend that creating string primitives should be preferred rather than creating string object as String primitives only require memory to store the raw string value itself.

But internal what happens is that when a method is called on a string primitive, JavaScript creates a temporary string object to perform the method operation.

So isn't this process more costlier?

Comment: Can you show a code example?

Comment: More importantly than any tiny performance differences, using built-in types in their object wrapper forms is bad practice and leads to surprising behavior because for example `new String('a') != new String('a')`, also any string methods return strings and not `String` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The String() constructor has an overhead, otherwise after the string creation they seems the same in terms of speed.

So your question:

> So isn't this process more costlier?

Seems the opposite...

And a more generic answer - what you code in JS isn't what a JS engine performs internally... Consider that as a black box which you can benchmark only. But remember that you should update your benchmarks when the JS engine's new version is released.

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="500000000">

  // @benchmark string literal

  const str = 'one two';
  // @run
  str.indexOf('two');

  // @benchmark String 

  const str2 = String('one two');
  // @run
  str2.indexOf('two');

  // @benchmark string literal initiation
 'one two'.indexOf('two');

  // @benchmark String constructor
  String('one two').indexOf('two');



</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```